# redis lua check and set does not work

Tags: lua, redis

After running the following script by `redis-cli.exe --eval test.lua`, `get foo` still prints 1.

```
local current = redis.call('GET', 'foo')
-- I have also tried current = redis.call('GET','foo').ok
if current == 1
    then redis.call('SET', 'foo', 2)
end
if current == '1'
    then redis.call('SET', 'foo', 3)
end
```

Comment: I tested this with windows 3.2.100, and it has this problem, but I tested with mac using ldb it performed normal. So I guess something is corrupted with redis lua for windows.

Comment: did you check that if the value of `foo` is still `'1'` while running from windows?

Comment: @ruhul yes, in Windows, `redis-cli --eval *.lua` does not set `foo` to a new value, because `if` never matches. Moreover, both windows `cmd` and windows `bash` does not work as expected with `--ldb` so I could not figure out what `current` it sees.

Comment: @ruhul I believe it is windows `redis-cli` problem, because I could use lua with jedis using the same redis server.